# Save state and values of a Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code:

```
var cards = [
    {
        name: 'John',
        age: 26
    },
    {
        name: 'Marc',
        age: 27
    },
    {
        name: 'Nathan',
        age: 21
    }
];
var save = cards;
for(var i = 0;i < cards.length; i++){
    if(i == 0){
        cards.splice(i,1);
    }
}
cards = save;
```

And at the end cards and save are the same, Marc and Nathan. And I want my cards be the array it was before, but I can't understand why it is not.

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6g8bkauo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var save = cards.slice()
```

NB. the card references, the objects in each array, will still be shared.

Answer (score 0):

Your referencing the array, you have to make a copy, just do it like this using [lodash](https://lodash.com/)

```
var save = _.cloneDeep(cards);
```

Or without a library:

```
var save = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cards));
```